# test suite inside spring context

Tags: spring, junit, spring-test, test-suite

Is it possible to run test suite with loaded spring context, something like this

```
@RunWith(Suite.class)
@SuiteClasses({ Test1.class, Test2.class })
@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "classpath:context.xml" }) <------
public class SuiteTest {
}
```

The code above obviously wont work, but is there any way to accomplish such behavior?

This is currently how spring context is used in my test suite:

```
@BeforeClass
public static void setUp() {
    final ConfigurableApplicationContext context =
            loadContext(new String[] { "context.xml" });
    jdbcTemplate = (JdbcTemplate) context.getBean("jdbcTemplate");
    // initialization of other beans...
}
```

Answer (score 10):

I have tried you code, the test suite are running with spring context loaded. Can you explain in more detail what the problem is?

here is the code:

```
@RunWith(Suite.class)
@SuiteClasses({ Test1.class, Test2.class })
public class SuiteTest {
}

@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "classpath:context.xml" })
@Transactional
public class Test1 {}

@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "classpath:context.xml" })
@Transactional
public class Test2 {}
```

If you want Suite class to have its own application context, try this:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "classpath:context.xml" })
@Transactional
public class SuiteTest {

    @Test public void run() {
        JUnitCore.runClasses(Test1.class, Test2.class);
    }

}
```

Comment: well I want Suite class to have its own application context

Comment: if it's done with `JUnitCore.runClasses` then it's ordinary JUnit test not a test suite

Comment: why do we need to put ContextConfiguration annotation in each test class ?

Comment: Spring intelligently caches the application context for a test suite – typically when we execute tests for a project, say through ant or maven, a suite is created encompassing all the tests in the project.

https://www.javacodegeeks.com/2012/09/spring-testing-support-and-context.html