# How to load application context Once for multiple Test classes

Tags: spring, junit, spring-test, test-suite

I have two test classes

```
public class Test_1 {

    @Autowired
    private Gson gson;

    @Test 
    public void test_1_1 () {
        assertNotNull(gson);
    }
}

public class Test_2 {

    @Autowired
    private Gson gson;

    @Test 
    public void test_2_1 () {
        assertNotNull(gson);
    }
}
```

Both require spring application Context. But instead of giving @RnWith(SpringRunner.class) & @ContextConfiguration(classes = {Config.class)}) on both the classes I want to initialise Application Context once. And at the same time I should be able to run single(any test through eclipse) test.
Is this possible.

Gone through this : [test suite inside spring context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17484191/test-suite-inside-spring-context). but its  loading the application context but not available in Test_1 or Test_2 (gson is null).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reuse spring application context across junit test classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8501975/reuse-spring-application-context-across-junit-test-classes)

Answer (score 1):

> Yes, this is perfectly possible. All you have to do is to use the same
>   locations attribute in your test classes:
>
> @ContextConfiguration(locations = "classpath:test-context.xml") Spring
>   caches application contexts by locations attribute so if the same
>   locations appears for the second time, Spring uses the same context
>   rather than creating a new one.
>
> I wrote an article about this feature: Speeding up Spring integration
>   tests. Also it is described in details in Spring documentation:
>   9.3.2.1 Context management and caching.
>
> This has an interesting implication. Because Spring does not know when
>   JUnit is done, it caches all context forever and closes them using JVM
>   shutdown hook. This behavior (especially when you have a lot of test
>   classes with different locations) might lead to excessive memory
>   usage, memory leaks, etc. Another advantage of caching context.

source this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8502023/3892213)